# HTML5 Mark Element

Tags: html

Which browsers and their versions, IE, FF Google Chrome, Opera, for example, FireFox 2.0, 3.0 support the `mark` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see! http://browsershots.org/http://jsbin.com/evixu4 <s>(results pending)</s>

[Test code](http://jsbin.com/evixu4):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="hello">Hello <mark>World</mark></p>
</body>
</html>
```

As rendered on Chrome 10.0.648.204 on Windows 7:

[image]

---

#### Edit w/[Browsershots results](http://browsershots.org/http://jsbin.com/evixu4)

All browsers tested will render text inside of `<mark>` (as is typical for rendering unknown elements). The following are the browsers tested, with items in **bold** indicating which browsers apply special styling (in all cases tested, this means a yellow background) to `<mark>` elements. Presumably, the highlighted style indicates that the browser supports the element.

#### Chrome

- Chrome 5.0.375.99 (Debian)
- **Chrome 9.0.597.107 (Windows XP)**
- **Chrome 10.0.648.133 (Ubuntu)**
- **Chrome 10.0.648.204 (Windows XP)**
- **Chrome 11.0.696.16 (Ubuntu)**
- **Chrome 12.0.712.0 (Ubuntu)**

#### Firefox

- Firefox 1.0.8 (Ubuntu)
- Firefox 2.0.0.20 (Windows XP)
- Firefox 2.0.019 (Ubuntu)
- Firefox 3.0.3 (Ubuntu)
- Firefox 3.5.8 (Ubuntu)
- Firefox 3.6 (Windows XP)
- Firefox 3.6.10 (Ubuntu)
- **Firefox 4.0 (Debian)**
- **Firefox 4.0 (Windows XP)**

#### IE

- IE 6.0 (Windows XP)
- IE 7.0 (Windows XP)
- IE 8.0 (Windows XP)
- IE 8.0 (Windows 7)

#### Opera

- Opera 8.54 (Windows XP)
- Opera 9.63 (Debian)
- Opera 9.80 (Ubuntu)
- Opera 9.80 (Windows XP)
- Opera 10.00 (Debian)
- Opera 10.60 (Debian)
- Opera 11.01 (Ubuntu)

#### Safari

- Safari 4.0 (Windows XP)
- Safari 5.0.4 (Windows XP)
- Safari 5.0.4 (Windows 7)

<sub>(In case it's not obvious, results are sorted by brand, then version, then OS tested.)</sub>

---

All screenshots (zipped): https://github.com/downloads/mjball/Stack-Overflow-Q-A/110331-103924-jsbin.com-6183471.zip

Comment: which is the earliest version of support?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc I believe someone recently serially downvoted me (similar to [this incident](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/)). At any rate, I decided to [earn it back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506258/) depite being (very) rep capped for the day. Shrug

Answer (score 0):

As of today, IE 9, FF 4, and Chrome 12 support it, but Safari 5 does not.  Tested using most current versions of browsers on a Win 7 box.  They render it like a yellow highlighter.