# HTML5 Mark Element Question

Tags: html

Is the mark element an inline or block element.

Answer (score 1):

the [mark element](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/text-level-semantics.html#the-mark-element) may contain "phrasing content", which is essentially equivalent to being an `inline` element.

Answer (score 0):

It's inline. That should be pretty obvious from the test markup used in [my previous answer about `<mark>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502418/html5-mark-element-question/5502515#5502515). There's no line break before or after the element, so it's not a block element.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-mark-element