# Horizontal scroll overflowing HTML <li>'s without knowing width

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/waitinforatrain/DSSPb/2/

I want to arrange a bunch of `<li>` elements which represent images in a horizontal scrollable container, like in the example above.

The tricks I've seen so far set the width of the container to be the width of the `<li>`elements. However, I have no way of knowing what the width of the container will be because the content is dynamic.

Is there a way to do this with CSS without knowing the container width?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps? http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/5JRdZ/

- change `ul` and `li` `display` to `inline-block`
- remove `li { float: left; }`
- add `ul { white-space: nowrap; }` so the `<li>`s don't wrap to the next line when the `<ul>` is too narrow

Now your problem is solving the `li { height: 100%; margin: 4px }` causing the `<li>`s to be taller than the `<ul>`. (Here's the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/avTgR/ :)

Comment: Works perfectly. When you're at CSS long enough it's easy to forget that floating layouts are a hack!